# Menu problems driving me NUTS

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a WordPress site running the DIVI theme which works OK except for the menu.
When the browser width is < 982 the menu is the hamburger, all well and good.
When the browser window is > 982 & < 1516 the menu is vertical NOT what is required.
When the browser window is > 1516 the menu is horizontal which is what I hoped it would be!

Furthermore, I have the sticky plugin installed such that as the user scrolls the menu sticks at the top of the page, at this point the vertical menu becomes horizontal.

I have spent hours trying to solve this, got passed logic and went deep into poke and hope which is not my choice of problem-solving, no joy.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the problem can be? My theory is that it is something so stupid I have been missing it for days.

You can see the problem at https://udsl.com

Many thanks.

Comment: Usually somewhere in the CSS there is a width parameter that dictates which style will be used. IE: mobile, web, tablet, etc.  I'm not familiar with Divi theme but this page might be of use to you: 

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/using-divis-new-height-width-options-to-create-responsive-design

Comment: Thanks, gives me a target to look into.

Comment: Went over everything again and noting has max-width set.

Answer (score 1):

After much aggravation, a friend suggested that it might not be something I had done wrong. Turned out she was right, was a bug in the template update. Good that it was not my error, annoying for al the time wasted trying to find my mistake that was not there!